# Control ViewFlipping in Android Widget

Tags: android

Here is what I have to do:

I want to create a widget which plays a short video clip. So, what I did is, to do screenshots of the movies and get a series of screenshots of it and switch the image in a certain frame rate to achieve what I want.

In here, I used ViewFlipper and a number of ImageView under it. But the problem comes.

I have no idea how to set ViewFlipper to flip through all the ImageView once and stop at the last one. I tried to set it as AutoStart true and set it back to false after a certain time (using Handler) but it doesnt work.

can anyone help?

Comment: Please accept some answers from your older questions. People are more likely to give you answers if you give them credit for it.

Comment: accept previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `stopFlipping()` on view flipper?

Comment: because i am controlling the viewflipper through remoteviews, i cant directly operate the viewflipper to call stopFlipping...